# Working with Char in c programming

Tags: c

I am a newbie in c programming language and I have a university tutorial assignment that is related with working with chars(I wont be graded for this assignment) where you have to count words, I have to compile and submit my answers in an online web environment where my code will run against test cases that are not visible to me.here is my assignment:

> Write the function 'wc' which returns a string containing formatted as follows: "NUMLINES NUMWORDS NUMCHARS NUMBYTES" . 
>   Whitespace characters are blanks, tabs (\t) and new lines (\n). A character is anything that is not whitespace. The given string is null-char (\0) terminated.

here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
char* wc(char* data) {
  char* result ;
  int numLine ;
  int numWords ;
  int numChars ;
  int i;
  int numBytes =strlen(data);
  char* empty=NULL;
  while(strstr(data,empty)>0){
    numWords=1;

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(data); i++) {

    if(data[i]=='\n'){
     numLine++;
   }
    if(data[i]==' ' ){
     numWords++;
   }
    if(data[i]!=' '){
     numChars++;
   }
   }

   }

    sprintf(result, "%d %d %d %d", numLine, numWords, numChars, numBytes);
    return result;
}
```

this code will give me the correct output result but I am missing something here at least the test tells me that.

Comment: If you are indeed getting the correct result, then what do you mean by "I am missing something"?

Comment: He doesn't know the exact test cases being used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got a very serious error:

```
  char* result;
  ...
  sprintf(result, "%d %d %d %d", numLine, numWords, numChars, numBytes);
```

This is not allowed in C. You need to allocate sufficient memory for the string first. Declare `result` as a large enough static array, or use `malloc` if you've covered that in your course.

e.g.

```
char buf[100];  // temporary buffer

sprintf(buf, "%d %d %d %d", numLine, numWords, numChars, numBytes);

char *result = malloc(strlen(buf) + 1);   // just enough for the string
strcpy(result, buf);                      // store the string

return result;
```

Comment: changed it to this : char* result =malloc(sizeof(data)*strlen(data)) ;

Comment: @Solix `sizeof(char)` is always 1, by definition. And if it weren't, it should be `sizeof(*data)` or sizeof(data[0]) to get the size of the data pointed-to by the pointer.

Comment: @Solix - You need `strlen(data) + 1`, one extra for the terminating `\0`. But in this case, the string you're copying to is not the same as `data`. It'd be better to use a temporary buffer, `sprintf` to that, then use `strlen` to allocate `result`, and copy.

Comment: thanks for this answer i learned alot out of it about memory allocation. however after doing this still the tests wont pass

Comment: @Solix - It's probably best to post a new question with the code that doesn't work, and the tests you've done.

Comment: I dont have any tests cases of myself its only the tests that are invisible to me.

Comment: @Solix - I mean your own tests - to show what you're trying. If you can present a small example that would work if people tried to compile.

Answer (score 2):

What if you have this input?

```
Two        Words.
```

You have to count the transitions between whitespace/non-whitespace, not just count spaces.

---

Also, I'm pretty sure `strstr(data,NULL)` will not do anything useful.

Comment: luser do you mean I have to check '\t' as well?

Comment: That's what @kelberry says. And I agree. But I'm talking about multiple spaces between words.

Answer (score 1):

1)  **sizeof is wrong:**

Instead of `sizeof` operator you need to use `strlen()` in for loop, like:

```
for (i = 0; i < strlen(data); i++)
                ^ not sizeof
```

`sizeof(data)` returns only size of data pointer address that is `4`. Because you are to read all char in `data[]` you need `strlen()` that will return length of `data[]` (or number of chars in `data[]`)

2) **memory error:**

Next Error I can notice there is no memory allocated for `result`. it declare like:

```
char* result ;
```

and No memory allocate! and you are writing using `sprintf` that cause **undefined behavior** of your code

3) **while(strstr(data,empty)>0)** is wrong

`strstr()` search position of a string in to other you empty string is `NULL` , CHECK: 
[char *strstr(const char *s1, const char *s2);](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strstr.html)

you strstr() always returns `data`, Why are you calling this? I believe *you don't need* this `while()` loop.

I improved you code upto some extend as below, There was only three error as I mentioned above now corrected(*to understand read comments*), You basic algo is correct:

```
#define SIZE 256   // added size macro
char* wc(char* data)  
  char* result = malloc(SIZE*sizeof(char)); //(2) allocated memory for result 
  int numLine ;
  int numWords ;
  int numChars ;
  int i;
  int numBytes =strlen(data);
    numWords=1; 
                    // (3) remove while loop
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(data); i++) {  //(1) change size
        if(data[i]=='\n'){
         numLine++;
     }
        if(data[i]==' ' ){
         numWords++;
     }
        if(data[i]!=' '){
         numChars++;
     }
    }
    sprintf(result, "%d %d %d %d", numLine, numWords, numChars, numBytes);
    return result;
 }

int main(){
    printf("\nresult: %s\n", wc("q toei lxlckmc    \t \n ldklkjjls \n i \t nn "));
    return 1;
}
```

Output:

```
result: 2 14 28 41
```

Comment: thx man, I changed it to strlen(data) but still the tests fails.

Comment: @Solix there is other error also Like read second point in my updated answer

Comment: you are right about the errors and I have corrected it but still no chance to pass a single test case .

Comment: @Solix ok let me know if you need more help one this.Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

You also appear to be missing the `\t` for tab in your white space checker, and you're not correctly checking when you're in or out of a word. You can use the boolean type `bool` for this defined in *stdbool.h* for this.

Answer (score 1):

Source code of wc unix command:

http://www.gnu.org/software/cflow/manual/html_node/Source-of-wc-command.html

All test cases handled.